# About HTTP Server，The client receives the data that is not returned by the server

Tags: java, webserver, httpclient, nio, httpserver

This is Server and Client code,Please help me to see where the error，It can be post data to the server but httpResponse not received,Tell me why，Thanks！

imagcode: [POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYJkc.png)

```
public  void dopost(){
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1:8088");


        StringEntity params =new StringEntity("{\"username\":\"De\",\"passwd\":\"REsfg7ufghfgh\",\"public\":\"ERTYU45646\"} ");
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.addHeader("Accept","application/json");
        request.addHeader(new BasicHeader("Cookie","JSESSIONID=B6FF25530B16AB46CA77B08129FECFB3"));
        request.setEntity(params);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
        clientread();

        if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            if (httpEntity != null) {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(httpEntity.getContent(),"UTF-8"), 8 * 1024);
                StringBuilder entityStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    entityStringBuilder.append(line + "/n");
                }
                System.out.println(entityStringBuilder.toString());
                JSONObject resultJsonObject = new JSONObject(entityStringBuilder.toString());
                System.out.println(resultJsonObject.toString());
            }

        }

    }catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }

}
```

some server code :[SERVER2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErvR7.png)

Server code is:

```
else if (key.isWritable()) {
                    SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

                    JSONObject res1 = new JSONObject();
                    res1.put("result","OK");
                    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
                    byte[] bytes = res1.toString().getBytes();
                    buffer.put(bytes);
                    buffer.flip();
                    channel.write(buffer);
                    channel.shutdownInput();
                    channel.close();
                }
```

Comment: Please provide the codes in plain text, not as images. Also describe clearly what exactly the problem is - provide example input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: ok,Thanks for reminding

Comment: server did not return correct HTTP protocol